# Trying to assign a char pointer from another char pointer. Why is it segfaulting?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, character, whitespace, c99

Edited: This fixes the original segfault. But now I'm not sure why text2 is just storing NULL

```
char* text = "some text";    
char* text2 = malloc(sizeof(text2) * MAX_WORD_LEN);

while (*text != '\0'){
      *text2++ = *text;
      if(isspace(*text)){
           while (isspace(*text)){ 
                  *text++; 
           }
      }
      else{ *text++; }
      
}
```

why does this segfault? How should I be doing this?

Comment: `char* text2 = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_WORD_LEN);` should be `char* text2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_WORD_LEN);`, or better, `char* text2 = malloc(sizeof(*text2) * MAX_WORD_LEN);`

Comment: That said, the inner `while` looks a candidate for `if` instead.

Comment: @SouravGhosh thank you both! Both suggestions fixed the segfault. The string is now storing null, but at least its a step forward

Comment: @cdpp The loop does not make sense. It would be much better if you describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the size of a pointer when creating an array of char?

Comment: @cdpp, update the question title...

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several problems. I'm listing it below:

1. `char* text2 = malloc(sizeof(text2) * MAX_WORD_LEN);` what do you mean by `sizeof(text2)`, shoudn't it be `sizeof(char)`
2. You're increasing `text2 pointer`, then how could you be able to print `text2`, if doesn't know the start of `text2`, cause as you increased the pointer `text2` will only point '\0'.
3. there's also problem in your while loop...`while (isspace(*text))`, you're not checking here if you reached the `*text = '\0' or not`...

Ok, let me give the right version of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LEN 1024


/**
 * Note: this could also handle if spaces are the end
 *
*/


int main() {
    char* text = "some text  ";    
    char* text2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_WORD_LEN); // note: sizeof(char), cause string

    char *itr = text; // its better to put a seperate iterator to iterate over strings in c
    char *itr2 = text2; // declare a iterator to iterate over text2

    while (*itr != '\0') {
          *itr2 = *itr;

          // increase both iterator
          itr++;
          itr2++;

          // there's no need to provide a if here, just run while loop
          // also notice, previously by increasing "text" pointer you may reach the end
          // but, you're not checking it
          // but, you should check it
          while(*itr != '\0' && isspace(*itr)){ 
              itr++; // while iterating 
          }
     
          // there's no need to increase "itr" here
    }

    // finally at a null char to the end of text2
    *itr2 = '\0';

    printf("text: %s\n\n", text);
    printf("text2: %s\n", text2);

    // at last free allocated memory
    free(text2);

    return 0;
}
```

**[P.S.]: Just a reminder, the program I've provided you, it also handle spaces at the end. But if you want something better, then you've to handle spaces at front, middle and end...if all places...its a to do for you...**

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing null. But since you're incrementing `text2` every time you store into it, you no longer have a pointer to the beginning of the original `text2` string. At the end of the loop, `text2` points just past the last character that was copied.

Make a copy of `text2` to use in the loop, so that `text2` will continue to point to the beginning. Or use array indexing rather than incrementing the pointer.

```
char* text = "some text";    
char* text2 = malloc(MAX_WORD_LEN);
char *p = text2;

while (*text != '\0'){
    *p++ = *text;
    if(isspace(*text)){
        while (isspace(*text)){ 
            *text++; 
        }
    } else{ *text++; } 
}
*p = '\0'; // add null terminator
printf("result: %s\n", text2);
```